# Webhooks response empty in PayU Money Web Integration in Node

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am trying to set up webhooks in my Payumoney dashboard for Payment successful event, but every time payumoney sends me an empty body in the request.

I am sending a 200 response to the server (as mentioned in the docs) and I am receiving the request on my server (but the body of request is empty).

Answer (score 1):

The Webhooks of payumoney work only in Live Mode and not is test mode. I sent a mail to payumoney tech support which provided me with the information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add headers to your webhook. Please edit your webhook settings and set Content-Type as application/json.